# RAID disk not booting

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm

my hosting facility replaced disk /dev/sda for me and I've added it to the RAID via

```
sgdisk -R /dev/sda /dev/sdb

mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda1
mdadm /dev/md1 -a /dev/sda2 
mdadm /dev/md2 -a /dev/sda3
```

`cat /prod/mdstat` looks fine to me:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid0] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      729952192 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      524224 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      2096064 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

But when I reboot it doesn't work. When I do a `grub-install /dev/sda` it says

> /usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: This GPT partition label has no BIOS Boot
>   Partition; embedding won't be possible!. /usr/sbin/grub-setup: error:
>   embedding is not possible, but this is required when the root device
>   is on a RAID array or LVM volume.

When I try a `grub-install /dev/sda1` it says

> /usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: unable to identify a filesystem in
>   hd0,gpt1; safety check can't be performed.

Do I miss a step to get sda back to boot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check up on `parted`. I think you need to do something like this:

```
parted /dev/hda
set <partition number> bios_grub on
quit
```

Once you have that going, grub should be able to figure out where to put stuff. Then do this - or your own variation:

```
grub-install --modules=raid --no-floppy /dev/sda
```

This should make grub work again. I found lots of useful hints for doing much the same thing [here](http://www.wensley.org.uk/gpt).